# Event called by the control or its Parent control

Tags: winforms, events, parent

If there is a button within a group box on a win form, and when the "click" event occurs, then who is actually calling the Event. Is it the button contorl or its parent i.e. GroupBox.

Comment: Use the break point and try it I guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd have written a native Windows GUI program then it would be the group box that got the click message.  Buttons send notification to their parents.  But that gets re-routed in Winforms, both through sub-classing and having the container window reflect messages back to the child control.

Events always originate at the control.  Their OnClick() method in case of a click.  You however still handle the event at a higher level window.  Typically the form, not the groupbox.  The *sender* argument of the event handler passes a reference to the control.  Having a choice over exactly where you handle the event is a major advantage over the native way.  It makes controls highly adaptable and composable.